# Is it possible to define commonly used strings for all languages in laravel localization?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

So that I can use them like

```
{{ trans('common.string') }}
```

This would be handy for settings variables that are the same across all languages, for example, brands.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but for those who found it like me one way of doing it is to set the fallback_locale in config/app.php to a language and only write the common text for that language.

ex. If you set

```
'fallback_locale' => 'en'
```

and create a resources/lang/en/common.php file with

```
return ['foo' => 'bar']
```

now

```
@lang('common.foo') or Lang::get('common.foo')
```

will return 'bar' if there is no other common.php file in other locale folders.